# Updating a listview in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, refresh, fragment

I'm fairly new to programming for android and programming in general. I searched the web and stackoverflow for a solution, but can't seem to find one.

I have an app with different tabs handled in fragments. One of my fragments contains a listview. However, the listview won't updat or refresh. It should refresh when I get an incoming sms. Here is the fragment code:

```
public class SmsSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_sms, container, false);

        ListView mListData = (ListView) listView.findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        TextView aantalSms = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.aantalSms);

        ArrayList<SmsInfo> listSms = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("ListSMS");

        // check condition 
        if(listSms != null && listSms.size() > 0) {
                // set data to list
                SmsInfoAdapter adapter = new SmsInfoAdapter(getActivity(), listSms);
                mListData.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                int count = listSms.size();
                aantalSms.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        }

        return listView;
    }
```

The receiving of sms is handled in three other classes, the Receiver code is:

```
package com.example.android.effectivenavigation;
```

import... etc

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static ArrayList<SmsInfo> listSms = new ArrayList<SmsInfo>();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    // get SMS map from intent
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    // a notification message
    String messages = "";
    if ( extras != null ) {
        // get array data from SMS
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" ); // "pdus" is the key

        for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i ) {
            // get sms message
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
            // get content and number
            String body = sms.getMessageBody();
            String adition = "  SMS::  ";
            String einde = " ::SMS";
            String sendme = adition + body + einde;
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
            // create display message
            messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";
            messages += body + "\n";


            //Send to Arduino
            Amarino.sendDataToArduino(context, DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'T', sendme);


            // store in the list
            listSms.add(new SmsInfo(address, body));
        }

        // better check size before continue
        if(listSms.size() > 0) {
            // notify new arriving message
            //Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            // set data to send
            Intent data = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            // new activity
            data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            data.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ListSMS", listSms);
            // start
            context.startActivity(data);


        }
    }
}
```

Could someone shine some light on my problem?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition, as you can probably see what happens now is that te Mainactivity.class is started again. In this (second) spawn of the application (when sms is received) the list is updated with the last sms that spawned it. However, additional sms won't show up in the list, just in another new spawn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have nothing that actually updates the fragment. Your broadcast receiver is receiving information but you never add this to the fragment.

Do something like in your fragment declaration add:

```
private SMSReceiver receiver;
private IntentFilter filter;
```

In your onCreateView add:

```
receiver = new SMSReceiver();
filter = new IntentFilter(SMSReceiver.YOUR_STRING_FILTER);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

And then in your onReceive in the SMSReceiver class add something like:

```
adapter = new SmsInfoAdapter (this, yourData);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Having this all in the Fragment class is what I do.

Comment: I can't add the adapter and list.setAdapter (adapter)

Could this be because the receiver is in another file? SmsReceiver.java?

Also there are two more classes in different files that handle the incoming sms and put in in the list:

SmsInfo.java 
SmsInfoadapter

I got these from this example: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/create-an-application-auto-receiving-new-message-sms/

Maybe this makes my problem a little bit clearer? As I said I am fairly new to android/java so some of the basics might not (yet) be too clear to me...

Comment: Allthough I've got my arduino receiving the sms messages and scrolling them on a 8x8 led screen measuring 25cm x 25cm wich I think is awesome :)

Comment: As far as object oriented design goes, it probably would be best to create individual BroadcastReceiver classes for each place you need to update/modify UI elements. If the current one already works for something else, you could move it to where that one uses it, and create a separate one for this class. That way in the onReceive() you can just call a method/modify the list adapter and list easily.

The flow would then be: something sends broadcast ---> all of your receivers receive the data and modify what they need ---> happy programmer